# Python - comparing value to an element of list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let's assume i got list like this:

```
list = [[1],[3],[4],[5],[8],[9],[12],[14],[15]]
```

then for some `items` in `range(16)` i want to compare these `items` to list elements and if they are equals do something.

For my best try i got a code like this:

```
for f in range(16):
    if any(f == any(list) for x in list):
        print('f: ',f)
```

in this case it prints only once for the `f == 1`, where I want it to get `print()` for each equal elements. I'm pretty sure I'm comparing int to list and I'm not getting desired result but in case like this I don't know how to get to inners list values : -/

Comment: I don't think you understand what `any()` does

Comment: The phrasing of your question is a little confusing.  Would you say that you are trying to print all values in `range(16)` that appear in some sub-list of the variable `list`?

Comment: my code doesn't work so i'm looking fr help. Any() may be unnecessary here at all. @PatrickHaugh exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `any` here.  You should also rename `list` to avoid shadowing the built-in type by that name.

```
l = [[1],[3],[4],[5],[8],[9],[12],[14],[15]]

for f in range(16):
    if any(f in sub_list for sub_list in l):
        print('f:', f)
```

`any` accepts an iterable, and returns `True` if any element of that iterable is true and `False` otherwise.  What we are doing here is defining a generator comprehension `(f in sub_list...)` that checks each sublist for membership.  Since `any` short-circuits (i.e. it doesn't keep checking elements once it has discovered one is `True`), using a lazily evaluating iterator saves unnecessary effort.

What was happening in your original code was that `True` also has a numeric value of `1` (mostly for legacy reasons).  So since `any(list)` was always going to be `True`, `f == any(list)` is true only when `f` is `1`

Comment: Good answer, I just typed out a page answer using `zip()` before realising that the OP didn't want element-wise comparisons (after seeing this).

Comment: Thanks @Patric, it solved my problem. Im not using "list" as a name in my code, it's have been used only for a example here : -)

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'i' is not defined` when I try this code. Python 3.6.4. Any idea why?

Comment: @PaulH. When I refactored it to match the questions varaible names, i missed an `i` that should have become an `f`.  Thanks for catching that

Comment: That makes sense now. I am new to python and was trying to understand any(). BTW, you still have `(i in sub_list...)` in the explanation of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should try to have a list of integers. If it is not possible, I would use the following code:

```
l = [[1],[3],[4],[5],[8],[9],[12],[14],[15]]
for i in l:
    if i[0] in range(16):
        print(i[0])
```

Comment: Like I said above `list` phrase as a name of list is just an example. I'm not calling it like this in code. Aswell values in my list weren't like values I got in code, i know it has no sense to keep single integers inside list of lists, in my code its more like [[2,4],[5,7],[1,1]] etc.. Anyway thanks for fast reply ;-)

Comment: Integers inside lists is fine.  The point here is it's not a good practice to use builtins as variables, if if you are just presenting a hypothetical example.  A better name would be `list_` or `lst`.

Comment: @Slavg ok, You should keep in mind that when we do "in range" from Python 3.2 it is faster than using your list as it is being done in the previous response, also he is using two loops.